# Parameterized word report with tables

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a parametrized report via markdown from a shiny app. The report is supposed to be a wordfile containing text, images and tables. However I don't know how to imitate the behavior of the knit button via command line. Here is an example for the markdown file.

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: word_document
params:
  n: 10
---

```{r echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
params$n
df <- data.frame(x = 1:params$n, y = rnorm(params$n))
print(kable(df))
```
````

If I use the knit button in rstudio I get a "nicely" formatted table. The [tutorial](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html) for parametrized reports Ive been looking at suggest to execute the report with rmarkdown::render e.g.

```
rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd", params = list(n = 20))
```

However when doing so the table is not displayed as formatted table. The help for rmarkdown::render states that knitting is done if required. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: remove `results = 'asis'` and just write `kable(df)` (without print). This should result in the same table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That does help in the (hopefully) minimal example I provided. However I want to pass a list of identifiers to the markdown file and generate a table for each of the identifiers. Thus use a for-loop for which I do need the print call as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comment, this should work:

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: word_document
params:
  n: 10
  m: 20
---

```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
for(i in 1:length(params)){
  df <- data.frame(x = 1:params[[i]], y = rnorm(params[[i]]))
  print(kable(df))
}
```
````

And then you can use `rmarkdown::render("~/Schreibtisch/temp/RMD.Rmd", params = list(n = 10, m = 20))`

Does this work for you?

Comment: Hi thanks again. That does work indeed, although I dont understand why I couldnt get it to work before. I did some slight modification to be able to call the report with a variable number of "numbers" e.g. `rmarkdown::render("~R/report.Rmd", params = list(n = c(18,11,14,13)))`